# Definite integrals by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, self-learning

> If $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})} dx \ = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a} e^{-2ab}$, then the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})} dx $ is equal to?

To solve this problem I started by integrating by parts.

For ease of writing I kept  $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})} dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a} e^{-2ab} =  C $

Integrating by parts:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})}  = x^{-2}C - \int_{0}^{\infty} -2x^{-3} Cdx $$

$$= x^{-2}C + C  $$
$$ = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a} e^{-2ab}(x^{-2} + 1)$$

Is this the answer?

Comment: In last formula you have only constants in exponent power -  it's differentiation cannot give variable in exponent power under integral. So?

Comment: You can always differentiate your result and see if you get the function you started with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b^2=c$ then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a^2x^2-c/x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a} e^{-2a \sqrt{c}}$$
D.w.r.t. $c$ on both sides, to get
$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} e^{-a^2x^2-c/x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi/c}~e^{-2a\pi \sqrt{c}}.$$
Put $c=b^2$ to get the value of the improper integral that converges.

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind choosing to replace $c$ with $b^{2}$ and then differentiating with $c$ ? I have only known the method of taking **Integration by parts**. Also is there a way of solving this question by **Integration by parts**?

Comment: $c=b^2$ is not necessary. You may avoid this and differentiate it w. r.t. %b$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})} dx ,\>J=\int_{0}^{\infty} {x^{-2}}e^{-(a^{2}x^{2} + \frac{b^{2}}{x^2})} dx 
$
and note that

\begin{align}
aI-bJ=e^{2ab}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(a-\frac b{x^2}\right)\> e^{-(ax + \frac{b}{x})^2}dx\overset{ ax+\frac bx\to x}
=0
\end{align}
Thus,
$J= \frac ab I = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2b} e^{-2ab}
$.

Comment: A good solution!